# DataGridComboBoxColumn does not display ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Sample code:

```
class GameListViewModel {
    private IGameRepository repository;
    public GameViewModel GameViewModel { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<GameViewModel> Games { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<GenreViewModel> Genres { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddGame_ { get; set; }

    public GameListViewModel() {
        repository = new DummyGameRepository();
        GameViewModel = new GameViewModel();
        Games = new ObservableCollection<GameViewModel>(repository.GameList().Select(game => new GameViewModel(game)));
        Genres = new ObservableCollection<GenreViewModel>(repository.GameList().Select(game => game.Genre).Distinct().Select(genre => new GenreViewModel(genre)));
        AddGame_ = new RelayCommand(AddGame, CanAddGame);
    }
}

class Game {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public int Pegi { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,32">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sub-Title" Binding="{Binding SubTitle}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pegi" Binding="{Binding Pegi}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Genre" Binding="{Binding Genre.Name}" />

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Test" ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The problem is, I want the combobox to show all the possible genres added to games, dynamically. For that I have created a ObservableCollection within GameListViewModel. It does not work! I have been struggling with this now for 2 hours... Later I want the selected value to be the Genre within the Game.

Answer (score 6):

Ahhh, you have discovered the source of many WPF developer's fustrations - the DataGrid does not forward it's DataContext to the columns.   You can't really rely on statements like ItemsSource={Binding Genres}" in the column, because the framework can't resolve it.  It's super-annoying.

Also, you have not set your SelectedItemBinding - here is a working example:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Possibilities}" x:Key="possibilities"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="test" 
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Selection}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource possibilities} }">

            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

cs code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
            {
                new Item(){
                    Selection ="A"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _selection = null;

    public string Selection
    {
        get { return _selection; }
        set { _selection = value; OnPropertyChanged("Selection"); }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _possibilities = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "A", "B", "C"
    };

    public ObservableCollection<string> Possibilities
    {
        get
        {
            return _possibilities;
        }
        set
        {
            _possibilities = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Possibilites");
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propChanged != null)
            propChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here are some helpful links:
this one should work:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx

the last solution shown here is particularly relevant:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx

Comment: But the context for loading the input is (for now) not within the datagrid context, only the selected value should be... And the solution the example gives me does not solve my problem... Is there another way?

Comment: I believe that my earlier comment still stands - you can't expect to bind directly to the VM from the column a-la ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}".  In my updated example, I'm using a static resource to get around your first issue.  Later, when you implement an item-specific set of Genre possibilities, you will have to use something more like what I included in the links.