# WPF MVVM DataGridComboBox Column Unique ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

In my WPF MVVM project, I have a DataGrid filled with an ObservableCollection (CaseCardEquipmentList) and a ComboBox Column. Each ComboBox in the ComboBox Column needs to be filled with an ObservableCollection (SerialNumList) relative to a value in its respective row. Is this possible to do? For example, if there are the following values in the DataGrid:

```
Equip Type | OEM Name | Equip Name | Equip Model | Serial Num |
-----------|----------|------------|-------------|------------|
    Nav    |  Global  |  System 2  |    v.2.1    |  COMBOBOX  |
   Shoes   | Footwear |   Adidas   |     Old     |  COMBOBOX  |
   Shirt   |   UA     |  Clothing  |    Smelly   |  COMBOBOX  |
```

...the ComboBoxes would need to show all Serial Nums (SerialNumList) related to an underlying identifying property "OPEquipIDNum" in each individual row of the ObservableCollection CaseCardEquipmentList . How do I go about this?

**XAML**

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="Auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CaseCardEquipmentList}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Equipment Type" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding EquipTypeName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="OEM Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding OEMName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Equipment Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding EquipName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Equipment Model" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding EquipModel}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SerialNum">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SerialNumList}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="SerialNum"
                                      SelectedValuePath="FacilityEquipIDNum"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFacEquipIDNum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
private ObservableCollection<ALLCaseCardEquipPrep> _caseCardEquipmentList;
public ObservableCollection<ALLCaseCardEquipPrep> CaseCardEquipmentList
{
    get { return _caseCardEquipmentList; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _caseCardEquipmentList, value, () => CaseCardEquipmentList);

        if (_caseCardEquipmentList != null)
        {
            GetSerialNumList(CaseCardEquipmentList);
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<FacilityEquipment> SerialNumList
{
    get { return _serialNumList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _serialNumList, value, () => SerialNumList); }
}

public Int32 SelectedFacEquipIDNum
{
    get { return _selectedFacEquipIDNum; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedFacEquipIDNum, value, () => SelectedFacEquipIDNum); }
}

public void GetSerialNumList(ObservableCollection<ALLCaseCardEquipPrep> ccel)
{
    foreach (ALLCaseCardEquipPrep item in ccel.ToList())
    {
        facilityequipment = new FacilityEquipment();
        facilityequipment.fillFacEquipSerialNumList(item.OPEquipIDNum);
        SerialNumList = facilityequipment.FacilityEquipmentList;
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public FacilityEquipment(int count, int facilityequipmentidnum, string serialnum)
{
    Count = count;
    FacilityEquipmentIDNum = facilityequipmentidnum;
    SerialNum = serialnum;
    FacilityEquipmentList = new ObservableCollection<FacilityEquipment>();
}

public void fillFacEquipSerialNumList(int opequipidnum)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
    {
        FacilityEquipmentList = new ObservableCollection<FacilityEquipment>();
        con.Open();
        string Query = "SELECT Fac_Equip_ID_Num, Serial_Num FROM facility_equipment WHERE OP_Equip_ID_Num ='" + opequipidnum + "' ";
        MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 1;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int FacilityEquipmentIDNum = dr.GetInt32(0);
            string SerialNum = dr.GetString(1);
            FacilityEquipment facequip = new FacilityEquipment(count, FacilityEquipmentIDNum, SerialNum);
            FacilityEquipmentList.Add(facequip);
            count++;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you showed looks like it should produce what you want already, so I am not sure what you question is. Or why you even use a ComboBox here to select? Could you elaborate?

Comment: The Comboboxes come up blank. I need to apply a specific Serial Num to the item in the row. After all items have a selected Serial Num, I would like to use the resulting SelectedFacEquipIDNums for a another list.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083769/datagridcomboboxcolumn-does-not-display-observablecollection), also you don't need to use DataGridTemplateColumn since wpf datagrid already has DataGridComboBoxColumn built in.

Comment: There is a surprising amount of questions on "how to bind ObservabelCollection to combo box?". This toutorial looks decent: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/

Comment: Christopher - For instance, I may have 5 pairs of old adidas shoes and need to choose a specific pair by their Serial Num. Same for Shirts, etc. Also, I believe that link is geared toward standalone Comboboxes. These ComboBoxes are within a Datagrid and need to all be populated at the same time dynamically with the varying number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1.Take a ObservalbleCollection/List in you ViewModel named "AllSerialNumbers" (I used in example below).

2.Take id/unique of your selected serial number for that product. (in example - SelectedSerialNoId)

3.Check following example for binding. This code will go and find DataContext of current window and it will find all the serailnumbers from ObeservableCollection (step-1)

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="SerialNumber" 
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedSerialNoId}"
                                SelectedValuePath="SerialNoId"
                                DisplayMemberPath="SerialNumber"
                                >
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.AllSerialNumbers}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Each row's Combobox must have it's own set of unique Serial Nums for that particular row. Searching through 10,000+ Serial Nums for each row is not reasonable. Does this code accomplish that? If so, can you further explain?

Comment: You can add selected SerialNumbers Collection at Model Level and then user different collection to bind the combobox.

Comment: In that case, you need not to go and find the datacontext while binding.